# How do I simulate a mouse click event

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to show the first image of my image gallery when it is loaded.
How would I go about simulating a mouse click event that will pass an event value to a function?

Here is my code:

```
private function createThumbContainer(my_X:Number, my_Y:Number):void{
    ThumbsContainerMC = new MovieClip();
    ThumbsContainerMC.buttonMode = true;
    ThumbsContainerMC.x = my_X;
    ThumbsContainerMC.y = my_Y;
    addChild(ThumbsContainerMC);

    // Here I am trying to enter displayImg() with the value of 0 in my evt.target.name
    //ThumbsContainerMC.getChildByName("name").dispatchEvent(new Event(MouseEvent.CLICK));

    ThumbsContainerMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayImg);
}

private function displayImg(evt:MouseEvent):void {  

    var imgURL = imgList[Number(evt.target.name)];
    imgTitle.text = imgURL.@label;

    if (evt.target.name != activeImg) {
        imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(imgURL));
    }
    activeImg = evt.target.name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you modify your code like this:

```
private function displayImg(evt:MouseEvent = null):void {  
    var name: String = evt ? evt.target.name : '0';
    var imgURL = imgList[Number(name)];
    imgTitle.text = imgURL.@label;

    if (name != activeImg) {
        imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(imgURL));
    }
    activeImg = name;
}
```

you'll have just to call `displayImg();` to init your gallery

Comment: Thanks this worked as well. I had trouble with understanding it but it worked :)

Comment: @ jtdino - this should help : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#conditional

Answer (score 4):

You don't really have to. Just move the displayImg code to a function with a string argument. Now it will be callable without the mouse event. Something like:

```
private function createThumbContainer(my_X:Number, my_Y:Number):void{
    ThumbsContainerMC = new MovieClip();
    ThumbsContainerMC.buttonMode = true;
    ThumbsContainerMC.x = my_X;
    ThumbsContainerMC.y = my_Y;
    addChild(ThumbsContainerMC);

    // Here I am trying to enter displayImg() with the value of 0 in my evt.target.name    
    loadImg("0"); 

    ThumbsContainerMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayImg);
}

private function Img_Clicked(evt:MouseEvent):void {  

   loadImg(evt.target.name);

}


private function loadImg(String targetName) {

    var imgURL = imgList[Number(targetName)];
    imgTitle.text = imgURL.@label;

    if (targetName != activeImg) {
        imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(imgURL));
    }
    activeImg = targetName;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's also common practice to make the event object argument optional and implement default behavior, like so (note that `int` would be the better number type to use here as you're accessing an array index):

```
private function createThumbContainer(my_X:Number, my_Y:Number):void{
    ThumbsContainerMC = new MovieClip();
    ThumbsContainerMC.buttonMode = true;
    ThumbsContainerMC.x = my_X;
    ThumbsContainerMC.y = my_Y;
    addChild(ThumbsContainerMC);

    // Here I am trying to enter displayImg() with the value of 0 in my evt.target.name
    //ThumbsContainerMC.getChildByName("name").dispatchEvent(new Event(MouseEvent.CLICK));

    displayImg();
    ThumbsContainerMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, displayImg);
}

private function displayImg(evt:MouseEvent = null):void {  

    var imgIndex:int = evt ? int(evt.target.name) : 0;

    var imgURL = imgList[imgIndex];
    imgTitle.text = imgURL.@label;

    if (imgIndex != activeImg) {
        imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(imgURL));
    }
    activeImg = imgIndex;
}
```

Comment: when evt is null will casting evt.target.name equal to 0? I doubt it.

Comment: @loxxy casting null to int will give you 0, but in this case you'd be accessing a property of null first (evt.target) which will throw an error...

Comment: Well that's what I was referring to. The above situation where the casting wont give 0 but an error.

Comment: The code checks for evt being null with a ternary operator: "evt ? evt.target.name : 0" is the same as "if (evt!=null){imgIndex=evt.target.name;} else {imgIndex=0;}", so there won't be an error.

Answer (score 3):

You could of course manually dispatch a MouseEvent.CLICK on the image:

```
myContainer.dispatchEvent (new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

Beware, though, automation of user events often leads to glitches in the program: What if the user clicks somewhere else first, maybe you want to have other listeners attached, etc.

I find it more useful to separate functions:  An event handler should contain only handling of the event, displayImg would become a separate method.

```
private function onThumbClick (ev:MouseEvent) : void {
    var name:String = evt.target.name;
    displayImg ( name );
}

private function displayImg ( name:String ) : void {
    var imgURL = imgList[parseInt (name)];
    imgTitle.text = imgURL.@label;

    if (name != activeImg) {
        imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(imgURL));
    }
    activeImg = name;
}
```

You can then call `displayImg ("1");` instead of dispatching an event.